# Cannot stop a running docker container

Tags: docker, centos, docker-compose

I am trying to stop a running container using my compose file.

Executed `docker-compose down`. I am getting following error. Other containers are stopping without any issue, only this particular container is not stopping. Tried removing by force but still failed.

```
ERROR: for <<CONATINER_NAME>>  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=70)
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

Comment: If it's not a strict requirement to use `docker-compose down`, you can try to stop them with `docker compose stop` or simply `docker stop`

Comment: Hi  Jose, I tried that as well, didn't work. Other than that tried `docker kill` as well. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server restart fixed the issue for me